# Supported source version 'RELEASE_6

Tags: java, jpa

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

- Esta es la advertencia que me muestra la consola antes de ejecutar
  el archivo jpa las librerias que tengo son las primefaces (estoy
  utilizando sus etiquetas) itext, poi más el glashfish

mensaje de la imagen:

> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
> 1 warning

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no alcanzo a ver la imágen, puedes convertirla a texto?

Comment: claro ya la cambio

Comment: Si me puedes ayudar te lo agradezco en verdad, la otra pregunta que me intentaste ayudar ya la pude resolver

Comment: usas eclipselink de casualidad?

Comment: Este es un bug de los raros del JDK https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037955

Comment: Nop @ruslan lopez